# Is it possible to align items relatively to each others in LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have multiple LinearLayout (orientation=horizontal), each one contains a TextView and a Spinner.

These Linear Layout are inside a LinearLayout (orientation=vertical) .

The TextViews are aligned to the left of the screen, and I'd like the spinners to be left-aligned to each others.

Is it possible or do I have to use a RelativeLayout or something else ?

Comment: use a constraint layout with a guideline. Or use layout_weight if you really must use linear layout

Comment: can you add your existing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `TextView` and the `Spinner`, set this:

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

This way the `TextView` and the `Spinner` are half the width of the layout so the Spinners are aligned. You can change the weights as you like.

In order for this to work, you must set for the `TextView` and the `Spinner` also:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

Comment: Hey, I tried this, and it didn't fully work, but I didn't know about the "width=0dp" thing. I'll try again on monday.

Comment: Great ! I had layout_width on "wrap_content", that's why my weight were not working so good, thanks. I remove the unnecessary"weightSum="2" from your answer if you don't mind, cause it would be redondant information.